# Fetching rows in DB2

Tags: db2, fetch

I know in DB2 (using version 9.7) I can select the first 10 rows of a table by using this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable
ORDER BY id
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
```

But how can I get, for example, rows 11 to 20?
I can't use the primary key or the ID to help me...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Without the explicit order there's no guarantee that you will fetch the same 10 rows every time. You'll need to add `ORDER BY` to your query.

Comment: You're right. I just updated my query. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's a sample query that will get rows from a table contain state names, abbreviations, etc.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT stabr, stname, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY stname) AS rownumber
   FROM states
   WHERE stcnab = 'US'
) AS xxx
WHERE rownumber BETWEEN 11 AND 20 ORDER BY stname
```

> Edit: `ORDER BY` is necessary to guarantee that the row numbering is consistent 
>   between executions of the query.

Comment: Yes, it did the job. Thanks!

Comment: whenever I add the where clause in the end I get `SQL Error [42703]: ROWNUMBER IS NOT VALID IN THE CONTEXT WHERE IT IS USED. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=4.19.26`

Comment: @GabrielZiegler - it sounds like you've got a syntax error in your query. Be sure you are enclosing your entire FROM clause in parents ( ) and have the "AS xxx" part to define your temporary table.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the MYSQL compatibility. You just need to activate the vector compatibility for MYS, and then use Limit and Offset in your queries.

```
db2set DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR=MYS
db2stop
db2start
```

- An excellent article written by DB2 experts from IBM https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/limit_offset?lang=en
- Compatibility vector in InfoCenter http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.porting.doc/doc/r0052867.html
- A blog about this http://victorsergienko.com/db2-supports-limit-and-offset/