# Range Selection DB2 Into VS2013

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, db2

I have to do range selection to get some data, and I have this query. Thanks to this [question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861902/fetching-rows-in-db2) and this [question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265850/how-to-query-range-of-data-in-db2-with-highest-performance)

**QUERY QUESTION 1**

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DKUREG ASC) AS NUMBER, 
SIMDTA.ACRDKL.* 
FROM SIMDTA.ACRDKL 
WHERE DKKDCB = 1403 AND DKCOB = 70 AND DKBKTG = 4011 AND DKTHRG = 2019) 
AS A WHERE NUMBER > = 1 AND NUMBER < = 100
```

**QUERY QUESTION 2**

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DKUREG ASC) AS NUMBER,
SIMDTA.ACRDKL.*
FROM SIMDTA.ACRDKL 
WHERE DKKDCB = 1403 AND DKCOB = 70 AND DKBKTG = 4011 AND DKTHRG = 2019)  
AS A WHERE A.NUMBER BETWEEN 1 AND 100
```

I've managed to get all the 100 data in DBVisualizer with this query.
But when I paste the code into Visual Studio 2013, I got this

[image: Error].

Comment: The Visual Studio error message mentions invalid SQL tokens which do not appear in your two sample queries. Are you sending different SQL than you provided in this question? Is the MsDb2Client rewriting your SQL before it sends the query to Db2?

Comment: The quote are added by the visual studio. It is rewrote by tge MsDb2Client

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the original SQLs directly in Db2 without the Visual Studio/MsDb2Client.  If it works fine, there might be a problem with the Visual Studio/MsDb2Client rewrite component.  If so, you may need to contact Microsoft.

Thanks.

Comment: It works when I run in DB2. I think I might. Thanks hidehy